# [__NSCFString NSInteger]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, unrecognized-selector

Why I have this error when I'm trying to **recover/compare** my `NSInteger`

```
[__NSCFString subTag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This is how I have declared subTag, which is part from an object called OptionSubView:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger subTag;
```

Then, I'm trying to compare this property, and my code crash:

```
for(OptionSubView *subV in self.optionsSubViews)
{
        if( subV.subTag == segControl.tag)
        {
            subViewSelected = subV.tipo;
        }
}
```

Comment: The error tells you that `subV` is a `NSString` instead of a `OptionSubView`. Verify how you add elements to this array.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I already solved even when I don't understand why my object was a string instead OpctionSubView object...

Answer (score -2):

I hope this helps you

```
for(id subV in self.optionsSubViews){
     if([subV isMemberOfClass:[OptionSubView class]]){
        OptionSubView *subview = subV;
        if( subview.subTag == segControl.tag){
           subViewSelected = subview.tipo;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but subV always was a NSString... What I did is OptionSubView *sV = [self.optionsSubViews objectForKey:subV]

Comment: @user1600801 In that situation you have to use isMemberOfClass: method